# Amazon Appstore DRM - How to implement?

Tags: android, drm, amazon-appstore

I haven't been able to find out much from Amazon on how their DRM works or how to even implement it, nor can I find any documentation worth a damn on it at all.

Does Amazon alter the APK themselves or is this something the developer has to do?

Is there some decent doc (designed for developers) explaining it? Please post link if you have it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to *do* anything but check the DRM checkbox when uploading your appliaction.

Comment: If you submit a signed APK can they still add DRM to it? If you submit an unsigned APK, then do they provide a way for you to sign it later and re-upload it? Not that I can see. I've been having a lot of trouble with them in general. Bad support, long delays, poor documentation.

Comment: Its also not too cool if they are altering the APK and then give you no way to test it before its launched in the store.

Comment: So as of yesterday they added some new functionality to the Amazon Developer portal. They now have a way for you to upload an unsigned APK, then download their modified version of it, sign it yourself, then re-upload it. They also give the option of letting them sign it. In either case you can choose to let them add the DRM or not.

Answer (score 0):

From the [FAQ](https://developer.amazon.com/help/faq.html):

> **Can I apply DRM to my app?**
>
> For each app
>   that you submit to the Appstore, you
>   can choose to apply DRM or make your
>   app available without any rights
>   management constraints. If you do
>   choose to apply DRM to one of your
>   apps, you must use the DRM system
>   provided by Amazon through the Amazon
>   Appstore Developer Portal.

Have you already joined the developer program and tried to access the portal?

Here are more [details](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/03/07/amazon_android_drm/). I'm still trying to figure out if any of this has even happened yet, or if it's just being hyped up.

Comment: Yes, I have access to the portal. Nothing on DRM there that I can see. No DRM system provided at all. No detailed docs.

Comment: Thanks for the link, which had their blog post link in it: http://www.amazonappstoredev.com/2011/03/index.html. Has some good details, but still not enough. For example they talk at the bottom about whether the user will be able to use DRM apps when they don't have internet access. The answer is yes, a token is installed that gives them those rights, but then we see this:"The Amazon Appstore client will periodically communicate with Amazon servers to refresh the token." Which of course raises questions of how long the token lasts for, etc.